# Reordenar os id de uma tabela [PHP & Mysqli]

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, id

Olá, estou em um projeto em que a ordem dos id's e bastante importante para o resultado final, porém quando removido um linha da tabela fica sobrando um id vazio... Ex.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu apagar o id 2 vai ficar assim...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria que o código após apagar ele alterar todos os ID...
Já retirei o auto-incrementar para pode modificar porem n consigo ta ai meu codigo onde o $mate = nome_da_tabela;

```
<?php

include"default.php";

if (isset($_GET['mat']) && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $mat = $_GET['mat'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    include"../ligacao.php";

    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM ".$mate);
    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($linhas == $id) {
        mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE FROM ".$mate." WHERE id = '$id'");
    } elseif ($id < $linhas) {
        mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE FROM ".$mate." WHERE id = '$id'");
        $idn = 1;
        while ($idn > $linhas) {
            mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE ".$mate." SET id = '$idn'");
            $idn ++;
        }
    }

} ?>
```

O resultado e apenas o apagamento da linha sem alterar os id's dos demais.

O que eu faço ?

Comment: isso é loucura... teria que fazer update em cada linha alterando a chave primária... a chave primária existe pra justamente ser única e não ser alterada. Explique o que seria "importante para o resultado final" que certamente há outra forma de fazer o que você precisa

Comment: Você pode criar uma outra coluna na tabela, por exemplo, codigo, e alterar esse valor, mas não o id. Ou na tabela fazer um `i++` no loop e imprimir na primeira coluna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isto não faz qualquer sentido. os ids são um identificador único no ecosistema e não são permutaveis nem devem ser.
Se o Goytai tiver o ID 1 e eu o ID 2, se voçê morrer de causas naturais não pode dar o seu id a outra pessoa visto que esse ID é o numero que o identifica a SI e SO A SI em vida ou morte.

Comment: Obrigado... Se eu criasse uma nova coluna na tabela e usasse como se fosse um "ID" sem ser a chave primária, essa estrutura de código funcionaria no novo sistema proposto ?

Comment: sim. se criar outra coluna pode alterar os valores como quiser usando o UPDATE ou quando cria o novo elemento.